# Javascript var inside another var

Tags: javascript, typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I'm JS novice,
My problem is that I have a var `resortuid` its value is from PHP (it's working). I need to open a json file with `resortuid` in link. In other words I need to replace `XXXX` in url with `resortuid` var. I'm sure that it is a banal question, but not for me.
EDIT: codefrom first response is working on SO, but not in TYPO3 fluid template, my new question is how to pass it to fluid template?

```js
var resortuid = '1125';
var settings = {  
    "url": "https://aaa.aa/XXXX_simple.json",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
};
```

Comment: You can simply concatenate the strings, are you asking for the _most efficient_ way?

Comment: instead of changing the original question you should open another question. so the first answer matches your question and will not stand alone.

Answer (score 4):

You can use JavaScript [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
const resortuid = '1125';
const settings = {  
  "url": `https://aaa.aa/${resortuid}_simple.json`,
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
};
      
console.log(settings.url)
```

By the way, [Var, Let, and Const – What's the Difference?](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/) might be worth reading.

Comment: Thanks, now i know that the problem is not in JS but in my CMS, i want to use this code in Fluid template for typo3 extension. The problem is that both fluid and JS are using {}, so i need help from typo3 community, will edit my question